# docker container networking to connect localhost in one container to another

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I am using the default bridge network for docker (and yes, I am relatively new to docker). I have two docker containers.

The first container provides a service on port 12345. When creating this container, I did not specify the --publish option because I did not want to expose this port to the outside world.

The second container needs to use the service from the first container. However, the application running in this second container was hardcoded to access the service at 127.0.0.1:12345. Clearly, the second container's localhost is not the same as the first container. Is there a way to course docker networking to think that localhost in the second container should actually be connected to the port in the first container, without exposing anything to the outside world?

Answer (score 2):

Option N:   (this works but may not be the best solution)

One way you can force this to behave the way you need is through injecting an additional service to bind to the port within on the application container and redirecting it outward.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:12345,fork TCP:172.18.0.2:12345
```

A quick test here, I was able to confirm 127.0.0.1:12345 is treated as the remote 12345

Things to consider:

- The two containers needs to be able to reach each other
- It breaks the recommendation of one service per container.
- Getting the app into the docker container.  (yum / apt-get install socat, source build = ?)
- Getting it to run on startup on container start/restart.